# Is there a way from stopping screens overlapping on each other like this in react native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native, react-navigation

I've followed the react navigation example exactly, however my screens keep stacking on top of each other like this initially it gives the error

> Found screens with the same name nested inside one another.

However, even in the cases where I give them unique names it still occurs. Anyone have any idea how to fix this? I'm using the latest version (6.x) example in the react navigation docs.

[image]

[image]

Comment: You are nesting screens with the same `name`. Your `Tab.Navigator` screens render components with nested screens of the exact same name.

Comment: Even after I set unique names, it still occurs, you can see in the second screen shot i've changed the stack navigator name to 'HomeScreen' and the same thing is happening, unless I'm misunderstanding you?

Answer (score 3):

Your screens will be nested like that, what you can do is hide the header of the stacks.
Something like this:

```
export default function App() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer
      options={{ headerShown: false }}
    >
      <Tab.Navigator>
        <Tab.Screen name="HomeStack" component={HomeStackScreen} />
        <Tab.Screen name="SettingsStack" component={SettingsStackScreen} />
      </Tab.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

You can find description of headerShown here: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/bottom-tab-navigator#headershown

Comment: Yes, I literally just found this out, this works great, thank you!

Comment: Great, good luck with further work!